# Silverlight control in itself is not showing

Tags: silverlight, user-controls

I have this issue, that I am trying to create a control which would have the same control within itself.

My control code is here:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SubEventsControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:currentControl="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="400"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ItemsControl x:Name="SubEventsItemsControl"
                      Grid.Row="0"
                      Margin="5,0,5,5"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ControlSubEvents}"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Template>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <!--  Header  -->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <!--  Sub event text  -->
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                       Margin="3"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Style="{StaticResource DynamicTextBlockStyle}"
                                       Text="{Binding Path=SubEventName}"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap" />


                            <Border Grid.Column="1"
                                    Width="10"
                                    Height="10"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                    Background="{Binding RegistrationStatusId,
                                                         Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}}"
                                    CornerRadius="5"
                                    ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding RegistrationStatusLabel}" />
                        </Grid>

                        <!--  Subevent's subevents  -->
                        <currentControl:SubEventsControl Grid.Row="1" ControlSubEvents="{Binding Path=SubEvents}" />

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the class behind this is like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class SubEventsControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private PortalDomainContext _portalDomainContext;
        private EntityCollection<SubEvent> _controlSubEvents;

        public SubEventsControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public PortalDomainContext PortalDomainContext
        {
            get
            {
                return _portalDomainContext;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_portalDomainContext != value)
                {
                    _portalDomainContext = value;
                    this.NotifyChange("PortalDomainContext");
                }
            }
        }

        public EntityCollection<SubEvent> ControlSubEvents
        {
            get { return _controlSubEvents; }
            set
            {
                if (_controlSubEvents != value)
                {
                    _controlSubEvents = value;
                    NotifyChange("ControlSubEvents");
                }
            }
        }


        // Dependency properties declaration
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SubEventsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ControlSubEvents",
            typeof(EntityCollection<SubEvent>),
            typeof(SubEventsControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnTestEventsChanged));

        private static void OnTestEventsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {   
        }


        protected void NotifyChange(params string[] properties)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                foreach (string property in properties)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use it on another control and I get the first level, but not the second level, what am I doing wrong? Am I missing some binding issues? I think I should be possible, but maybe I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can't nest an instance of a control in itself *declaratively* as that would result in infinite recursion.

Best add instances of your control to instances of the same control as child elements **via code**.

Comment: What event should I use then? I do not see method, that I could use, maybe I am also looking from the wrong place? Does the ItemsControl control have some method/event to load it? Or which event should I use?

Comment: Ok, I think I will just generate whole form dynamically then. I have to figure out how to do it, thanks for the answer. If somebody has a good answer, they can reply here anyway.

Comment: Why not just use another type of control in the template? Do you require more than two levels of depth?

Comment: Yeah I need more than two levels of depth and I do not know the depth unless on binding time. I actually added controls dynamically now, so basically the question is off the limits for me, but maybe it can help someone else save the time.